# Postgres column too big to clear out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

A little less then 2 hours ago I notice a big issue in my code. Because of an accidental infinite for loop I filled a column `List.keywords` in my database with a gigantic piece of text. Everything blocked.

When I realised the mistake I changed my code to empty that column on each save of the records. Everything kept blocking.

I tried to migrate the database by using rails migration `remove_column :lists, :keywords`. That migration failed too.

Although that last migration must have done something as now the code is fast again. Except for `Lists` (where the column `keywords` gave me the issue). When saving a `List`, it takes about 5 seconds to do so. Reading it is fast.

If I do `heroku pg:psql` and check out the lists table, the `keywords` column is still there, so I'm guessing that's where all the data still is and why the table is so slow.

How would you guys resolve this?

Comment: How did the migration fail? What was the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that calling a `List` record would try to load this one into memory. The column was so huge that even this would fail in Rails.

#### My resolution after talking to a Postgres Engineer:

I logged into my postgres production console on heroku using `heroku pg:psql -a <myapp>`. I checked out what the value was for List 2203

```
SELECT "keywords"
FROM "lists"
WHERE id = 2203;
```

I saw that there was a huge chunk of text in this and was very happy because this was the first time I could actually see the problem. To start I wanted to clear **this** list

```
-- Doing this in a transaction, so if I don't like what happened, I can call ROLLBACK; to start over
BEGIN;
UPDATE "lists"
WHERE id = 2203
SET keywords = '';

SELECT "keywords"
FROM "lists"
WHERE id = 2203;

-- I was happy with the result as it was empty, so I committed the transaction
COMMIT;
-- If you're not happy, do ROLLBACK; to start over
```

Alright, this was one `List` done, time to do the all of them

```
-- not setting the WHERE as I want to do this on all of them.
BEGIN;
UPDATE "lists"
SET keywords = '';

-- here you can SELECT to do some checks at some records, see if they are empty.

COMMIT;
```

Voila, my Rails app started going fast again and nothing clogged up anymore.

Hope this can help somebody in the future. Probably me.